# Duda params axios node petición GET

Tags: nodejs, axios, get

Estoy intentando hacer una petición a la API con Axios y Node y que me coja los query params, pero no he conseguido que me los devuelva...

Disculpad mi ignorancia...pero llevo varios días sin poder sacarlo.

La pregunta original es:

First endpoint will return this data (https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/5f69afbe65b18913fc510ce8). It also allows query params to filter by ‘country’ or ‘code’ and order by ‘vat’ the results. You should validate query params: filter (string), order (string and only[asc, desc]).

```
axios
  .get(`https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/5f69afbe65b18913fc510ce8?meta=false`, {
    params: {
      country: 'Austria',
      order: 'desc',
    },
  })
  .then(res => console.log(res.data.record));
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No estas haciendo nada mal, si exploras en las dev tools puedes ver la llamada que se hace y esta incluye los params correctamente, el problema es que la API no devuelve los datos filtrados

[ejemplo](https://codepen.io/feliper/pen/LYmdgRa)

Si pones la URl directamente en el navegador tampoco filtra nada

https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/5f69afbe65b18913fc510ce8?country=Austria&order=desc&meta=false

saludos !!

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero te invito a leer [answer]. Responder sólo con un link y poca o casi ninguna explicación se considera de muy baja calidad. Te sugiero que copies y pegues el código relevante en tu respuesta y no un simple link. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

el poblema es cuando toma los datos tiene que toma los datos utilizando   **response.data;** y utilice **${}** para añadir el texto en el link

tambien puede utiliza la consola del navegador para consulta mejor los proceso con **F12**

reemplaza

```
res.data.record
```

por

```
 res.data
```

otro problema que si vi es que el orden de los datos cambia
en el Json Aparece  record y otro no aparece dependiendo del link

```
     consultaApi() {
                    axios
                        .get(`https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/5f69afbe65b18913fc510ce8? 
country=${Austria}&order=${desc}&meta=${this.estado}&consulta_data=${this.consultaDataInput}`)
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.info(response.data)
                            this.consultaDatos = response.data;
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            if (error.response.status == 401) {
                                location.reload();
                            }
                        });
                },
```